# Scipy & Ipython Notebook: how to save and load results?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, jupyter-notebook

Now I'm using Ipython Notebook.
There is part of my program need a long time to get the result, so I want to save the result and load it when next time I use the script. Otherwise I need to repeat the calculation and need a lot time for this.

I'm wondering is there any good practice of `saving and load` results? which makes it easier to resume the script the next time I need it?

It's easy to save `text` results, but in `scipy`, `numpy`, the result may be quite complex, e.g. `matrix`, `numerical array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options, such as [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html), which allows you to save almost anything. However, if what you are going to save are numeric numpy arrays/matices,  [np.save](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [np.load](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.load.html) seem to be more appropiate.

```
data = # my data np array
np.save('mypath', data)
data = np.load('mypath')
```